# SQL is works, but is there any way to make this smaller (sqlfiddle included)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this querys, its working and i am getting what i needs

SQL in short (more examples in a sqlfiddle provided below)

```
# Case 1: Return those who do have active subscription (subscriptions and access_rights is for debugging only)
SELECT a.*,
  (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT (s.subscription_id,' => ',s.is_active) SEPARATOR ', ')) AS `subscriptions`,
  (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT (ar.access_right_id,' => ',ar.is_active) SEPARATOR ', ')) AS `access_rights`
FROM account a
  LEFT JOIN access_right ar USING (account_id)
  LEFT JOIN subscription s USING (account_id)
  LEFT JOIN access_right active_ar ON active_ar.account_id = a.account_id AND active_ar.is_active = 1
  LEFT JOIN access_right inactive_ar ON inactive_ar.account_id = a.account_id AND inactive_ar.is_active = 0
  LEFT JOIN subscription active_su ON active_su.account_id = a.account_id AND active_su.is_active = 1
  LEFT JOIN subscription inactive_su ON inactive_su.account_id = a.account_id AND inactive_su.is_active = 0
  WHERE (active_su.account_id IS NOT NULL)
  GROUP BY account_id;

# Case 2: Return those who do have non-active subscription (active needs to be excluded, nulls must be shown)
SELECT a.*,
  (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT (s.subscription_id,' => ',s.is_active) SEPARATOR ', ')) AS `subscriptions`,
  (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT (ar.access_right_id,' => ',ar.is_active) SEPARATOR ', ')) AS `access_rights`
FROM account a
  LEFT JOIN access_right ar USING (account_id)
  LEFT JOIN subscription s USING (account_id)
  LEFT JOIN access_right active_ar ON active_ar.account_id = a.account_id AND active_ar.is_active = 1
  LEFT JOIN access_right inactive_ar ON inactive_ar.account_id = a.account_id AND inactive_ar.is_active = 0
  LEFT JOIN subscription active_su ON active_su.account_id = a.account_id AND active_su.is_active = 1
  LEFT JOIN subscription inactive_su ON inactive_su.account_id = a.account_id AND inactive_su.is_active = 0
  WHERE (active_su.account_id IS NULL)
  GROUP BY account_id;
```

Also, similar conditions will be applied for `access_right` table, and also there will be a combination of both conditions

Is there any way to shorten it?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14b347/15

Comment: iam tempted to say this is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on stackoverflow as the code works and the question seam to be about refactoring.. This seams more [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) which is a other stackexchange site

Comment: @RaymondNijland It needs some explanation of how and why before this would be acceptable though.

Comment: also @Mast i doubt about the correctness off the results off these queries aswell, as in SQL 1992 this SQL is invalid but in SQL 1999+ which has a optional feature which is called functional dependency this is allowed so these queries can be valid.. But should only be trusted if the topicstarter is using atleast MySQL 5.7.5...

Comment: @RaymondNijland its greater than 5.7.5

Comment: *"its greater than 5.7.5"* With enabled sql_mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` i hope (`SELECT @@sql_mode;`) ? Otherwise the functional dependency detection can still not be trusted (forgot to mention)

Comment: @RaymondNijland i am not sure about it... On my `local` and `dev` environments - yes, it is. But on a  production... This is a great headsup

Comment: instead of self joining to find/filter matching (non) active subscriptions i advice you use conditional aggregation as you already use `GROUP BY` there... see [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14b347/32) .. keep in mind the  `GROUP_CONCAT()` is/can be different because you should be using a `GROUP_CONCAT( .... ORDER BY ...)` to get a deterministic result there

Comment: @RaymondNijland  hmm this will not cover the case when we will need to filter only active, excluding in-active stuffs(not included in examples and not needed atm, but...) Also cant use `HAVING` in a way of "CMS" (quotes) works. but this is another story

Comment: Yes the second case is more "trickly" with conditional aggregation .. *"Also cant use HAVING in a way of "CMS" (quotes) works. but this is another story"*  In that case you also can't improve your existing queries..  Offtopic: Also mine opinion if a CMS/framework would forbid/stop me from using a standard SQL keyword like `HAVING` i would stop using it straight away it is not worth the trouble writing "workarounds" ...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to join multiple times if you just need if they got an active flag or not

```
# Case 1:
select a.*
from account a
LEFT JOIN subscription s on a.account_id = s.account_id
where s.is_active = 1;

# Case 2:
select a.*
from account a
where a.account_id not in 
    (select s.account_id from subscription s where s.is_active = 1);
```

Comment: hmm i didnt think about sub-query.. it looks deferentially  clearer. But join is needed anyway - there is other tables like `subscription_template` which is also in the system but irrelevant for current topic.